# Google Maps Encoded Polyline PHP Function

Tags: php, google-maps

I am looking for a PHP function that encodes an array of points into an encoded polyline.

The algorithm is described here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html

I can't seem to find any way to do this and I have searched all over to no avail.

Comment: Several of the steps do not make sense to me.. I don't even know how I would "left-shift the binary" and several of the other steps are confusing to me :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you seen this site:
http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/

It has encoders written in Javascript, PHP, Java, Ruby and Perl.

**UPDATE 2014-03-17**

The above link is dead here is a new link for the PHP class http://perassi.org/quickhacks/polyline/class.polylineEncoder.phps